# Issue installing cykhash in pyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having a problem when installing cykhash in pyCharm (needed to install the package pyrosm)

I have this error when trying to install the package:

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cykhash
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cykhash, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

i have already tried to unistall and install wheels, but i still have the problem. does anynone know how to solve it??